# Flickering Conky on KDE desktop

Tags: kde, conky

I have a problem with Conky installed from `conky-all` package. Here is my config:

```
conky.config= {
alignment = "top_right",
background = true,
border_inner_margin = 0,
border_width = 0,
top_cpu_separate = true,
default_color = ffffff,
default_outline_color = "000000",
--default_shade_color = "999999",
double_buffer = true,
draw_borders = false,
draw_graph_borders = true,
draw_outline = true,
draw_shades = false,
gap_x = 0,
gap_y = 28,
maximum_width = 222,
minimum_width = 222,
own_window = true,
own_window_hints = "undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager",
own_window_transparent = true,
own_window_argb_visual = true,
own_window_argb_value = 0,
own_window_type = "normal",
own_window_class = "conky",
show_graph_scale = true,
total_run_times = 0,
update_interval = 3,
text_buffer_size = 1024,
use_xft = true,
font = "Nokia Sans S60:size=8",
xftalpha = 1,
lua_load = "~/.conky/qkiz_rings-kde.lua",
lua_draw_hook_post = "main_rings",
};

conky.text = [[
${offset 16}${font OpenLogos:size=20}u ${voffset -7}${font Nokia Sans S60:size=14}Ubuntu Linux ${execi 3600 lsb_release -a | grep "Release" | cut -f 2}${font}
${offset 18}${voffset 5}${font OpenLogos:size=20}t${font}${voffset -8} ${kernel} ${voffset -10}${font Poky:size=15}S${font} ${voffset -3}${machine}
${offset 35}${voffset 5}${font Poky:size=13}w${font} ${voffset -5}${addrs wlp5s0} ${voffset -6}${font Poky:size=13}s${font} ${voffset -4}${uptime}
${font Poky:size=13}P${font} ${voffset -5}${font Nokia Sans S60:size=10}CPU${font} ${voffset -3}${hr}
${voffset 5}Freq:${freq cpu}MHz${alignr}Temp: ${acpitemp}°C
0${offset 50}1${offset 49}2${offset 47}3
${offset 15}${voffset 10}${font Nokia Sans S60:size=8}${cpu cpu0}%${font}
${offset 67}${voffset -13}${font Nokia Sans S60:size=8}${cpu cpu1}%${font}
${offset 119}${voffset -13}${font Nokia Sans S60:size=8}${cpu cpu2}%${font}
${offset 172}${voffset -13}${font Nokia Sans S60:size=8}${cpu cpu3}%${font}
${voffset 19}4${offset 49}5${offset 49}6${offset 47}7
${offset 15}${voffset 10}${font Nokia Sans S60:size=8}${cpu cpu4}%${font}
${offset 67}${voffset -13}${font Nokia Sans S60:size=8}${cpu cpu5}%${font}
${offset 119}${voffset -13}${font Nokia Sans S60:size=8}${cpu cpu6}%${font}
${offset 172}${voffset -13}${font Nokia Sans S60:size=8}${cpu cpu7}%${font}
${voffset 20}${cpugraph cpu0 25,48}${offset 6}${cpugraph cpu1 25,48}${offset 6}${cpugraph cpu2 25,48}${offset 6}${cpugraph cpu3 25,48}
${voffset -5}${cpugraph cpu4 25,48}${offset 6}${cpugraph cpu5 25,48}${offset 6}${cpugraph cpu7 25,48}${offset 6}${cpugraph cpu7 25,48}
Load: ${loadavg}${alignr}Proc: ${running_processes}/${processes}
${font Poky:size=13}M${font}${voffset -5}${font Nokia Sans S60:size=10}MEM${font} ${voffset -3}${hr}
${voffset 7}${font}RAM:${memperc}% Free:${memfree} / ${memmax}
Cache: ${cached} / ${buffers}
Swap: ${swapperc}% ${swap} / ${swapmax}
${memgraph 26,150}${font Nokia Sans S60:size=6}${offset 34}${voffset -21}ram${voffset 8}${offset -13}swp${font}
${voffset 3}${font Poky:size=13}y${font}${voffset -5}${font Nokia Sans S60:size=10}DISK${font} ${voffset -3}${hr}
${font}${voffset 20}${offset 13}${fs_used_perc /}%
${offset 50}${voffset -20}${font}Disk /${alignr}Use:${fs_used /}/${fs_size /}
${offset 50}${voffset 3}Free:${fs_free /}
${voffset 20}${offset 13}${fs_used_perc /home}%
${offset 50}${voffset -20}Disk /home${alignr}Use:${fs_used /home}/${fs_size /home}
${offset 50}${voffset 3}Free:${fs_free /home}${alignr}HDDTemp: ${hddtemp /dev/sda}°C
${font Poky:size=13}w${font}${voffset -7}${font Nokia Sans S60:size=10}NET${font} ${voffset -3}${hr}
${font}${voffset 8}Download:${alignr 0}Upload:
${font Nokia Sans S60:size=7}${downspeedf wlp5s0} kB / ${totaldown wlan0}${alignr}${upspeedf wlp5s0} kB / ${totalup wlan0}
${downspeedgraph wlp5s0 30,105 scale }${alignr}${upspeedgraph wlp5s0 30,105 scale }
${voffset -5}${font Poky:size=13}r${font}${voffset -5}${font Nokia Sans S60:size=10}TOP${font} ${voffset -3}${hr}
${voffset 5}Top CPU${alignr}CPU%   MEM%
${offset 13}1. ${top name 1}${alignr}${top cpu 1}     ${top mem 1}
${offset 13}2. ${top name 2}${alignr}${top cpu 2}     ${top mem 2}
${offset 13}3. ${top name 3}${alignr}${top cpu 3}     ${top mem 3}
${offset 13}4. ${top name 4}${alignr}${top cpu 4}     ${top mem 4}
${offset 13}5. ${top name 5}${alignr}${top cpu 5}     ${top mem 5}
Top MEM${alignr}MEM%
${offset 13}1. ${top_mem name 1}${alignr}${top_mem mem 1}
${offset 13}2. ${top_mem name 2}${alignr}${top_mem mem 2}
${offset 13}3. ${top_mem name 3}${alignr}${top_mem mem 3}
${offset 13}4. ${top_mem name 4}${alignr}${top_mem mem 4}
${offset 13}5. ${top_mem name 5}${alignr}${top_mem mem 5}
Top IO${alignr}IO%   Read   Write
${offset 13}1. ${top_io name 1}${alignr}${top_io io_perc 1}%   ${top_io io_read 1}   ${top_io io_write 1}
${offset 13}2. ${top_io name 2}${alignr}${top_io io_perc 2}%   ${top_io io_read 2}   ${top_io io_write 2}
${offset 13}3. ${top_io name 3}${alignr}${top_io io_perc 3}%   ${top_io io_read 3}   ${top_io io_write 3}
${voffset 0}${font Poky:size=13}n${font}${voffset -5}${font Nokia Sans S60:size=10}LOG${font} ${voffset -3}${hr}
${voffset 5}${execi 10 tail -n8 /var/log/syslog | fold -w52}
]]
```

The issue appears in Ubuntu 20.10. Flickering appears very often. Conky disappears for 1 second and appears updated on the desktop. This happens all the time and it is not dependent on CPU/disk usage. Setting `double_buffer = true` doesn't help.

I'm using KDE v5.19.5. (but the same issue happens on Gnome), gfx card is Intel HD Graphics 4600. There are no special settings for Conky in KDE window settings.

Comment: Perhaps it is taking over 3 seconds to create the new display; try increasing the `update_interval` to, say, 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was last line in config file `${voffset 5}${execi 10 tail -n8 /var/log/syslog | fold -w52}`. Every time when `/var/log/syslog` file changed Conky starts flickering. I made a workaround for this problem by leaving functionality untouched. First I made a script to tail syslog file which is creating a temporary file with few last lines of syslog and wrapping text around.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    tail -n8 /var/log/syslog | fold -w52 > ~/.conky_syslog_workaround.log
    sleep 10
done
```

The script is starting on logging in. Then I removed the mentioned line in config file with a new one.

`${voffset 5}${tail ~/.conky_syslog_workaround.log 20 10}`

Now working fine without flickering (which starts happening in Ubuntu 20.10).